# Eclipse servlet error

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I was working with a fully functional .war file I imported for a intro to Java tutorial I'm following. I had to change the jdk I was using (via the installed jre page). Now after changing this I'm getting a "javax.servlet cannot be resolved" error with my code. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You need to add servlet-api.jar into your classpath

Answer (score 0):

*check project build path whether `Servlets api. jar` file is included or not. you can add it in two ways:*

1) add **servlets api .jar** file to build path

or

2) add **server runtime** (i add Tomcat server runtime library) in build path

Hope this helps.